# Web Server returning 500 when sending large images

Tags: visual-studio, iis

I have an XML web service that is returning a 500 error, but only when I'm sending it large images. I don't have much experience with server side programming, but I think the issue is the request being cut off due to the size of the image. I would really appreciate any guidance towards how to fix this. Can I change the allowed size of the request? Either in the app.config or web.config or in IIS directly?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: First use FRT to learn more about the 500 error, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis and then probably debug why your web service returns that.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, if the error is caused by the file being too large, you only need to set maxRequestLength and maxAllowedContentLength to solve the problem.

maxRequestLength indicates the maximum request size supported by ASP.NET, whereas maxAllowedContentLength specifies the maximum length of content in a request supported by IIS.

About how to configuring maxRequestLength and maxAllowedContentLength you can refer to this link: [Configuring ASP.NET and IIS Request Length for POST Data](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Apr/06/Configuring-ASPNET-and-IIS-Request-Length-for-POST-Data)